Finding a first integral
$$
\mbox{I am given the system:}\quad
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\dot{x} & = & -y
\\
\dot{y} & = & \phantom{-}x + y^2
\end{array}\right.
$$
and am asked if the system contains periodic solutions and/or limit cycles.

The approach that is supposed to work is to determine a first integral, apply the Morse Lemma and from the result conclude there are periodic solutions but no limit cycles.
I fail to construct a first integral $\operatorname{F}\left(x,y\right)$, even though it should be easy I think.
I get stuck when I try the simple approach:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{F} & = \int\left(-\dot{y}\right)
{\rm d}x =
-\left(\frac{1}{2}x^{2} + y^{2}\right) + \alpha\left(y\right)
\\
\operatorname{F} & = \int\dot{x}{\rm d}y = -\frac{1}{2}\,y^{2} + \beta\left(x\right)
\end{align}
Now $\alpha,\beta$ can't be chosen such that $\operatorname{F}\left(x,y\right)$ satisfies both integrals.
The First Integral is supposed to be
$$
\operatorname{F}\left(x,y\right) =
\left(y^{2} -\frac{1}{2} + x\right){\rm e}^{2x}
$$

How do I get this result ?.



By the looks of it some integrating factor method seems appropriate, although I do not know how this works in higher dimensions.

Start with
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\dot y}{\dot x} = \frac{x+y^2}{-y}
.
$$
Multiply by $2y$ to obtain
$$
\frac{d(y^2)}{dx} = 2y \frac{dy}{dx} = -2 (x+y^2)
.
$$
With $z(x)=y(x)^2$ you get a linear ODE
$$
\frac{dz}{dx} + 2z = -2x
,
$$
which you can indeed solve using an integrating factor.
Maybe you can take it from there?

Okay I solved the 1 dim. ODE and have found that $ze^{2x} = -(x-\tfrac{1}{2})e^{2x} + C$ with C some constant, so this rewrites to $C = ...$ with the First integral expression on the right. I still dont see the connection between solving this ODE and the first integral expression of the system of ODE's

What you have shown is that any solution $(x(t),y(t))$ to your original system satisfies the relation $y(t)^2 e^{2x(t)} = -(x(t)-\tfrac12) e^{2x(t)} + C$ for some constant. So if you solve for $C$ you find a function of $x$ and $y$ which is constant on solutions $(x(t),y(t))$. In other words, you find a constant of motion (or an invariant, or a first integral, or whatever you prefer to call it).

Ahh yes I see. I never thought of starting out by dividing $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$ to find this relation between a $x(t)$ and $y(t)$. Is this a rather general procedure for finding these level curves in the phase space (perhaps just in $\mathbb{R}^2$)?

Yes, it's a standard thing to try for planar systems.
